# Showing equivalence in a complex measure space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

*I am trying to figure out how to answer this question in full.

Recall, that if µ is a complex Borel measure on R, then the maximal
function $M(µ) : \Re \to [0, 1]$ of µ is defined by
$M(µ)(x) = \sup_{r>0}\frac{|µ|(B(x, r))}
{\lambda^1(B(x, r))} $, where $\lambda$ denotes a Lebesgue measure in R.

Also, if $\phi : R \to [0, 1)$ is a Borel measurable function, then $\phi · \lambda$ denotes the measure defined by $(\phi · \lambda)(B) = \int_B\phi d \lambda$ for all Borel sets $B\subset \Re$

Let $f : R \to R$ be a Lebesgue integrable function. Show that the following
statements are equivalent.
(a) $M(|f| · \lambda) = 0.$

(b) $M(|f| · \lambda)$ is Lebesgue integrable

(c) $f=0$ Lebesgue a.e.*

**Solution**

I have been able to show that $a \iff c$ but I am struggling on how to start showing that $a \iff b$ and $b \iff c$.

My answer thus far:
We first note that $M(\mu)(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{|\mu|(B(x,r))}{\lambda(B(x,r))}=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{\lambda(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}|f|d\lambda$

Then we suppose that c holds such that,
$M(\mu)(x)=\sup_{r>0}\frac{|\mu|(B(x,r))}{\lambda(B(x,r))}=\sup_{r>0}\frac{1}{\lambda(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}|f|d\lambda=0$, 
then it is clear that a is also true.

Then for the converse we assume a is true yielding, 
$0=\int_{B(x,r)}|f|d\lambda$,
so we are able to deduce that f is Lebesgue measurable a.e. as it is non-negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once we establish $b \Rightarrow c$, then the rests follow directly. Assume to the contrary that $|f|>0$ on a set of positive measure. Then there exists a ball $B\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
\int_B |f(x)|dx=c >0.
$$ Without loss of generality, assume that $B= B(0,1) =\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\;|\;\|x\|<1\}$. Then, for $y$ with $\|y\|=r$, we have
$$\begin{eqnarray}
M(|f|\cdot\lambda)(y) &\geq& \frac{1}{|B(y,r+1)|}\int_{B(y,r+1) }|f(x)|dx\\&\geq& \frac{1}{|B(y,r+1)|}\int_B |f(x)|dx\\
&\geq& c'\cdot r^{-n}=c'\|y\|^{-n},
\end{eqnarray}$$ for some constant $c'>0$ and for all sufficiently large $r>0$. Conclude from this fact that $M(|f|\cdot\lambda)\notin L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Song, apologies if I am missing the point but how does this show condition c? Does it not just show that M is positive?

Comment: It's not just that $M$ is positive: our goal is to show that $M$ is not integrable (it is implied by the growth bound I gave actually.) Then we argue by contradiction. Suppose we succeed to show that $M\notin L^1$. This means that not $c$ implies not $b$. Now, $b\Rightarrow c$ is just the contrapositive of it. Hint: One way to see that $\int \|y\|^{-n}dy =\infty$ is to use spherical coordinates.